# Where can I do setup after loading my UITableViewCell subclass from a xib

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4, xib

I have to do some setup after loading my UITableViewCell subclass from a xib. I can't do it in

```
-(id)initWithCoder:aDecoder{}
```

because the IBoutlets haven't been set at this point. Is there another method after this point that is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IBOutlets inside:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```